# Deploy asp.net core 1.0 website on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc, web-deployment, asp.net-core-1.0

My website is using asp.net core 1.0 and angular 2. And I have account on amazon aws where i have a running ec2 instance (windows). Now I  want to deploy this website to that instance. 
my project struction is like

```
website
.
...src
   .
   ..Bussinesslayer
   ..DataAccesslayer
   ..webapp   <------startup project
     .
     ..wwwroot
```

How to deploy this site on aws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Found a way to publish to aws

**Steps**

```
1. Select your startup project 
2. Goto Buid > Publish < Selected Startup project >
3. Create a profile and provide location to local drive ( C:/ or d:/)
4. After publish is successfull just copy the entire content of the folder and paste in aws wwwroot folder
```

your website is live now :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy your files to your server using Remote Desktop (Note firewall may need to be opened for this)

You will need to create a web site in IIS
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/323972

During creating a new site, it will ask you what folder you put your code/files in.